# The transpose of a row vector in relation to dual spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, transpose

I read that the transpose defined for linear transformations has the following definition: [image]

I tried to apply this dual space definition of the transpose to a transformation induced by a row vector. For example say a row vector in $\widetilde{R^3}$ induces $S$ such that $S:R^3\to R$. The transpose of this transformation would be $S^T:R\to \widetilde{R^3}$. However, since the transpose of $S^T$ should be induced by a column vector (the transposed row vector), I was confused because I thought that a column vector should transform a vector from $\widetilde{R^3}$ to $R$ instead.

This has left me very confused. I am wondering how $S^T$ can be induced by a column vector and yet map from $R$ to $\widetilde{R^3}$. Or is this not making sense due to a difference between the transpose of a matrix and the transpose of a transformation that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it maps $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^3$. If $v$ is the column vector, then for $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$, the map is given by

$$ S^T(\lambda) = \lambda \, v $$

The map is just scalar multiplication by the column vector.

It is just matrix multiplication, actually. It is the product of the column vector (a $3 \times 1$ matrix) and the scalar (a $1 \times 1$ matrix).

Comment: In the formula it says that it maps from $R$ to the dual space of $R^3$, so why does it map to a column vector rather than a row vector? Does this definition of $S^T$ not apply here? I'm sorry, I'm very confused.

Comment: The coefficients in the column vector represent a basis of the dual space $\widetilde{R^3}$. If you represent $S^T$ as a matrix it has to be a column because the domain is 1-dimensional and the range is 3-dimensional. Maybe it's best to keep the "abstract" definition involving dual spaces in mind here, and not get too caught up in identifying the maps with the matrices that represent them in a certain basis.